# What are the differences between a Dictionary and containers.Map?

Tags: matlab, dictionary

Recently, in version R2022b they announced the introduction of [dictionaries](https://blogs.mathworks.com/matlab/2022/09/15/an-introduction-to-dictionaries-associative-arrays-in-matlab/?s_v1=46299&elqem=3876639_EM_NA_DIR_22-11_MOE-CG&elqTrackId=57bd4ffc6e664c4dba6f769bdd4495b0&elq=6ddfb16fe77f4ed29d5d887908a6cdcc&elqaid=46299&elqat=1&elqCampaignId=17102).

I was under the impression that dictionaries were already available, provided by [containers.Map](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html). Are dictionaries just a different name mapped to containers.Map? Or are there other differences? I was unable to find anything comparing them online.

Comment: There was some discussion about this in the Matlab chatroom; see [this comment](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/81987?m=55251779#55251779) and those near it. They seem to be very similar, but `dictionary` is built-in and feels more "native"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I can gather, after reading [this blog post and the comments under it](https://blogs.mathworks.com/matlab/2022/09/15/an-introduction-to-dictionaries-associative-arrays-in-matlab/), and the documentation (I haven’t yet had a chance to experiment with them, so feel free to correct me if I’m wrong):

1. `dictionary` is an actual primitive type, like `double`, `cell` or `struct`. `containers.Map` is a “custom class”, even if nowadays the code is built-in, the functionality can never be as integrated as for a primitive type. Consequently, `dictionary` is significantly faster.
2. `dictionary` uses normal value semantics. If you make a copy you have two independent dictionaries (note MATLAB’s lazy copy mechanism). `containers.Map` is a handle class, meaning that all copies point to the same data, modifying one copy modifies them all.
3. `containers.Map` can use `char` arrays (the old string format) or numbers as keys (`string` is implicitly converted to `char` when used as key). `dictionary` can use any type, as long as it overloads [`keyhash`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/keyhash.html). This means you can use your own custom class objects as keys.
4. `dictionary` is vectorized, you can look up multiple values at once. With a `containers.Map` you can look up multiple values using the `values` function, not the normal lookup syntax.
5. `dictionary` has actual O(1) lookup. <strike>If I remember correctly, `containers.Map` doesn’t.</strike>*
6. `containers.Map` can store any array as value, `dictionary` stores only scalars. The scalar can be a cell, which can contain any array, but this leads to awkward semantics, since retrieving the value retrieves the cell, not its contents.

<sup>* No, it is also O(1), at least in R2022b.</sup>

Comment: Re: point 1. Certainly `dictionary` is very well integrated, but I don't think it's really "primitive" in any way. It returns `true` to `isobject`. You can't interact with it in any simple manner from C(++). But it is definitely generally faster.